# 500 server error while trying to Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cash-on-delivery, http-error-500

I have a magento shop which is under development. While Im trying to checkout any product, it is giving me a 500 error. It started when i tried to implement Cash on Delivery from admin backend, payment methods. It gave me 500 error. So i tried to install another Cash on Delivery extension which gave me 500 error in entire checkout process. I tried to change the app folder, yet the error persists, so i believe its either server error or DB error. How can i Fix it[image]

Comment: Did you check your error logs in `var/log`? And if that gives no errors, you could also check the server's own error logs in `/var/log/apache/`

Comment: try to spot which is the exact error by looking at the error log of the web server and post it here to have further details

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /var/www/html/xxxx/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63, referer: http://xxxxx/index.php/checkout/cart/

This is the error im getting

trying to enable mcrypt on my php.ini

Comment: Yes mcrypt is required for Magento to work. You need to get this php extension enabled, that's your problem.